# Aws Cdk RestApi Cognito and IAM Authorization

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, aws-appsync

I'm trying to rebuild my `Amplify` project which currently uses `AppSync` with `Cognito` and `IAM` authorization modes. Since I want build all resources with the `CDK` and want to replace `AppSync` with an `API Gateway` I'm wondering how to support `Cognito` as well as `IAM` access.

So how do I implement `Cognito` and `IAM` (guest access) authorization for a `RestApi` built with `AWS CDK`?

`AppSync` already supports specifying both authorization modes:

```js
const api = new GraphqlApi(this, 'TodoTestAPI', {
  name: 'TodoTestAPI',
  schema: Schema.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, 'schema.graphql')),
  authorizationConfig: {
    defaultAuthorization: {
      authorizationType: AuthorizationType.USER_POOL,
      userPoolConfig: {
        userPool,
      },
    },
    additionalAuthorizationModes: [
      {
        authorizationType: AuthorizationType.IAM,
      },
    ],
  },
```

How do I do this with `RestApi` ?

My current code looks like this:

```js
const api = new RestApi(this, `RestApi`, {
      defaultMethodOptions: {
            authorizationType: AuthorizationType.IAM,
        },
      defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
            allowOrigins: Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
            allowMethods: Cors.ALL_METHODS,
        },
      cloudWatchRole: true,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I put this together for a lambda integration with an API Gateway. The `idToken` from a successful login to `Cognito` needs to be passed to the `Authorization` header with every API request.

You need to create an `authorizer` and attach that to your API gateway. Unfortunately, you can only have one type of `authorizer`. If you need to accommodate more than one, you can use a [`Lambda Authorizer`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) to run custom logic on your input tokens.

Here is an example of using just the `CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer`:

```js
  let api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, "knowledgeBaseApi", {
    description: "Used by the LLM Knowledge Base to integrate services",
    deployOptions: { stageName: "dev" },
    defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
      allowOrigins: ["*"],
      allowHeaders: ["*"],
      allowMethods: ["*"],
    },
  });

  let apiAuth = new apigateway.CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer(
    this,
    "cognitoAuth",
    {
      cognitoUserPools: [userPool],
    },
  );
  apiAuth._attachToApi(api);
```

Then, when you create your paths, you specify this `authorizer`:

```js
let home = api.root.addResource("home");

  home.addMethod(
    "GET",
    new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(lambdaProxyFunc, { proxy: true }),
    {
      authorizer: apiAuth,
// Also require passing "Authorization" as a header
      requestParameters: {
        "method.request.header.Authorization": true,
      },
      requestValidatorOptions: {
        validateRequestParameters: true,
      },
    },
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't really answer my question. I already know how to configure IAM or Cognito as authoriser but not how to enable both at the same time. At the moment it will probably only work via a lambda authorizer as you stated, but then I wonder how to verify the aws signature in the iam case.

Comment: Check out [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-api-gateway-and-iam/). It uses a lambda authorizer to look up policies stored in a `DynamoDB` table dependent on a user's `Cognito` group.